# Jquery toggle event is messing with checkbox value

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using Jquery's toggle event to do some stuff when a user clicks a checkbox, like this:

```
$('input#myId').toggle(
function(){
//do stuff  
},
function(){
//do other stuff    
}
);
```

The problem is that the checkbox isn't being ticked when I click on the checkbox. (All the stuff I've put into the toggle event is working properly.)

I've tried the following:

```
$('input#myId').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

and

```
$(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

and even simply

```
return true;
```

But nothing is working. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Edit - thanks to all who replied. Dreas' answer very nearly worked for me, except for the part that checked the attribute. This works perfectly (although it's a bit hacky)

```
$('input#myInput').change(function ()
{
    if(!$(this).hasClass("checked"))
    {
        //do stuff if the checkbox isn't checked
        $(this).addClass("checked");
        return;
    }

    //do stuff if the checkbox isn't checked
    $(this).removeClass('checked');
});
```

Thanks again to all who replied.

Comment: It's physically not showing in the browser as being checked when you click on it, or merely your event isn't firing?

Comment: The event is firing correctly and all the correct code is executing, but the checkbox just isn't getting checked! If I post the values from the form, the checkbox value isn't being posted through either.

Comment: Instead of using addClass, hasClass, and removeClass use toggleClass.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use the `change` event instead of the `toggle` event, like such:

```
$('input#myId').change(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        //do the stuff that you would do when 'checked'

        return;
    }
    //Here do the stuff you want to do when 'unchecked'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I had to add and remove classes rather than check attributes - for some reason I couldn't quite get that working. I'll post the full solution (at least what worked for me) above. Thanks again!

Comment: I've always wondered the practical difference between == and ===...what about this compare makes === necessary?

Comment: the '==' performs type coercion (conversion), meaning the compiler will implicitly try to convert the values. For example, [1 == true //true] because it converts the 'true' to a 1...but [1 === true //false] because a number is not equal to a boolean

Comment: instead of $(this).attr("checked") you can simply call this.checked and it will return checked value

Comment: I had to take the quotes off the "true" in case anyone has trouble with this function.

Comment: if($(this).is(:checked))  // better way to check

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the solution when I noticed my toggle function was unchecking the checkbox after my code ran in the event handler.

Answer (score 18):

While using the `change` event handler suggested by Dreas Grech is appropriate, it doesn't work well in IE 6 & 7, which doesn't fire the `change` event until the focus is blurred (that is, until you click outside the area of the checkbox). As [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html) say, "it's a serious bug".

You might want to use the `click` event handler, but that won't work with keyboard navigation. You need to register a `keyup` handler too...

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368807).

I haven't yet found a good cross-browser solution that supports both mouse clicks and keyboard activation of the checkboxes (and doesn't fire too many events).

---

Regarding your solution for checking whether the checkbox is checked or not, instead of adding your own `checked` class, you may use HTML's `checked` attribute:

```
$('input#myInput').change(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        //do stuff if the checkbox is checked
    } else {
        //do stuff if the checkbox isn't checked
    }
});
```

Any browser sets the `checked` attribute of an `input` element to the value `"checked"` if the checkbox is checked, and sets it to `null` (or deletes the attribute) if the checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 8):

why not using $.is() ?

```
$('input#myId').change(
    function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // do stuff here 
        } else {
            // do other stuff here
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer by MorningZ (I found it [here](http://old.nabble.com/how-do-you-toggle-a-checkbox-value--td19695519s27240.html)) that makes totally sense:

The part you are missing is that "checkbox" is a jQuery object, not a
checkbox DOM object

so:

`checkbox.checked` sure would error because there is no `.checked` property of a jQuery
object

so:

`checkbox[0].checked` would work since the first item on a jQuery array is the DOM object
itself.

So in your `change()` function you can use

```
$(this)[0].checked
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input#myId').toggle(
  function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do stuff      
    $(this).attr('checked', 'true');
  },
  function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do other stuff        
    $(this).attr('checked', 'false');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**this worked for me............ check it**

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
if($(this).attr("id").split("chk_all")[1])
 {
  var ty  = "sel"+$(this).attr("id").split("chk_all")[1]+"[]";
  if($(this).attr("checked"))
   {
    $('input[name="'+ty+'"]').attr("checked", "checked");
   }
  else
   {
    $('input[name="'+ty+'"]').removeAttr("checked");
   }
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar approach but simply using the checked attribute such as

```
 //toggles checkbox on/off
    $("input:checkbox").change(
        function(){
           if(!this.checked){
             this.checked=true;
           }
           else{
             this.checked=false;
           }
         }
       );
 //end toggle
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a non-jquery function:

```
function chkboxToggle() {
  if ($('input#chkbox').attr('checked'))
    // do something
  else
    // do something else
}
```

then in your form:

```
<input id="chkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="chkboxToggle()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
  if($(this).attr("checked"))
   {
    $('input[name="name[]"]').attr("checked", "checked");
   }
  else
   {
    $('input[name="name[]"]').removeAttr("checked");
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("input[type=checkbox][checked=false]")// be shure to set to false on ready
    $("input#Checkbox1").change(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $("#chk1").html("you just selected me")//the lable
        } else {$("#chk1").html("you just un selected me") }    
    });
```

Comment: works for me and I use it to check before some logic is applied. Very  handy to provide user feedback