# jquery show()/hide() problem in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

The following html code works in Firefox, but for some reason fails in IE (Label2 is not shown). Is that a bug or I miss something?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                function setVis(){
                    var val = $("#check").is(":checked");
                    if (val) 
                        $("#g_1").show();
                    else 
                        $("#g_1").hide();
                }

                setVis();
                $("#check").change(setVis);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
            <label>Label1</label>
        </span>
        <span id="g_1">
            <label>Label2</label>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Cause:

Per MSDN, the [change event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912(VS.85).aspx) is

> ...fired when the contents are committed
> and not while the value is changing.
> For example, on a text box, this event
> is not fired while the user is typing,
> but rather when the user commits the
> change by leaving the text box that
> has focus.

Behavior for checkboxes is similar: in IE the event does not fire until focus is removed from the element (try it: click then tab off of the checkbox and behavior is as expected). Firefox apparently does not respect this distinction.

#### Solution:

Use the `click` event handler instead of `change`:

```
            $("#check").click(setVis);
```

...and behavior should be consistent across browsers.

Comment: Most consider this a bug in IE: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-193-onchange-does-not-fire-properly.html

As soon as the selection in a radio set (or checkbox) is made, the value has changed.  IMHO, IE is the only browser that doesn't handle this correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that the onchange event is triggered **after you check the checkbox and then leave the checkbox**.  Did you try checking it, then clicking somewhere else on the document?

You may want to employ the **click** and keypress events in jQuery instead (for checking the box via click and spacebar).

`<sidequestion>`Is there any reason you're declaring/defining a function within your document ready paragraph, rather than outside of it?`</sidequestion>`

One more edit; may I recommend this sleeker code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#g_1").hide();
    $("#check").change(function() { $("#g_1").toggle(); });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help, you've got my vote. I posted the html code by stripping down the real (more complex) one, that's why it is not in the best shape. But still I see the value of your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Change the .change event to .click event. the result in both browser is the same. in IE when you click the checkbox, blur didn't occur.

Comment: That might be a problem if the box is checked when the page loads (via cookie or something).