# Show(), Hide() for class works for IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using one drop down list to determine what is displaed in another. My jquery .show() and .hide() works for firefox and not IE. I am using the class attribute to toggle. How would I do this for IE? Should I use javascript?

```
        if (dept == "All") {
            $('.Sales').show();
            $('.Acct').show();
        }
        else if (dept == "Sales") {
            $('.Sales').show();
            $('.Acct').hide();
        }
```

**EDIT**
dept is set to the value of the first drop down list

Comment: should work.. could be your missing quotes? and what is dept set to?

Comment: Your current example doesn't work in anything: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/VJS2j/).  Are those missing quotes a typo on the question?

Comment: I did miss my quotes, sorry about that. I do have it working in firefox, but not in IE, which is what puzzles me

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your missing a closing quote on `$('.Sales).show();`.  Shouldn't it be `$('.Sales').show();`?

Answer (score 0):

This could be because IE is not firing the on change event, please look at [jquery show()/hide() problem in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368807/jquery-show-hide-problem-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

You were missing single quotes...

If you have elements with class Sales and Acct, this should work in IE.
Remember that css is case sensitive. So class names must match.

```
    if (dept == "All") {
        $('.Sales').show();
        $('.Acct').show();
    }
    else if (dept == "Sales") {
        $('.Sales').show();
        $('.Acct').hide();
    }
```