# Change event not triggering until the document is clicked [JQUERY]

Tags: jquery

Hay guys, I'm using the solution found over at [Jquery toggle event is messing with checkbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355638/jquery-toggle-event-is-messing-with-checkbox-value) to fire an evert on a checkbox. IE however seems to have a bug, my event isn't being called until i click anywhere on the document.

any ideas?

sample code...

```
$(".selector").change(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        if(v == "0.00"){
            // some stuff
        }else{
            // some stuff
        }

    }else{
        // some stuff
    }   
});
```

**EDIT:**

It seems if i change .change to .click it works. Well at least on check boxes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

event bubbling/propogating issue or something like that i guess.

Comment: you need to study event bubbling/propogating for ie issues. This should be in dhtml books, articles, online tutorials, etc. You need to research a bit.