# Selecting and deselecting multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have this:

```
$('input.people').attr('checked', function() {
  return $.inArray(this.name, ['danB', 'lindaC']) != -1;
});
```

It is for a list of contacts.  I want to be able to have the user click a checkbox that will select the people in a specific role and uncheck everyone else.  That works.  Now I want to modify this so that if someone unclicks the same checkbox that it deselects those people (and only those people).  Would that be an `onBlur` event?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
$('input.people').attr('checked', function(){
   return $.inArray(this.name, ['danB', 'lindaC']) != 1;
});
```

or would it be:

```
$('input.people').attr('checked', function(){
   return $.inArray(this.name, ['danB', 'lindaC']) = -1;
});
```

And how would I integrate this with the top function?  A shout out, btw, to Nick Craver for his help to date.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.people').change(function ()
{
    if(!$(this).hasClass("checked"))
    {
        //do stuff if the checkbox is checked
        $(this).addClass("checked");
        return;
    }

    //do stuff if the checkbox isn't checked
    $(this).removeClass('checked');
});
```

Comment: see here for a discussion on why this works and what the shortcomings of other approaches are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355638/jquery-toggle-event-is-messing-with-checkbox-value