# Toggle click issue with checkbox

Tags: jquery, toggle

Please find the code below

```
$("#chkCopy").toggle(function () {
   copyDetails(); 
},
function () {
   emptyCopyDetails();
});

// functions which do not have any effect on the checkbox
function copyDetails() {

}

function emptyCopyDetails() {
}
```

The issue is that checkbox is not showing the checked state.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tmQ4a/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) interrupts the check, since [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) actually [calls `e.preventDefault()` on the `click` event underneath](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/event.js#L987).  Instead of that approach, I'd recommend something like this instead:

```
$("#chkCopy").change(function () {
  if(this.checked) {
    copyDetails();
  } else {
    emptyCopyDetails();
  }
});
```

[Here's an updated/working version of your demo with the above approach](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yJrCN/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#chkCopy").change(function () {                alert("1");

            },
            function () {
                alert("2");
            });
```

use change instead of toggle

Comment: This won't work, `.change()` doesn't have an overload with 2 handlers.

Comment: @Nick  you can also use      .click()

Comment: no...it also doesn't accept 2 handlers, `.toggle()` is a special function :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

> Since `.toggle()` internally uses a
>   click handler to do its work, we must
>   unbind `click` to remove a behavior
>   attached with `.toggle()`, so other
>   `click` handlers can be caught in the
>   crossfire. **The implementation also
>   calls `.preventDefault()` on the event,
>   so links will not be followed and
>   buttons will not be clicked** if
>   `.toggle()` has been called on the
>   element.

So you can't use `toggle()` if you want the check box to be checked and unchecked. You can use `click()` instead:

```
$("#chkCopy").click(function() {
   if (this.checked) {
       copyDetails();
   } else {
       emptyCopyDetails();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this answer you would accomplish the same thing

[Jquery toggle event is messing with checkbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355638/jquery-toggle-event-is-messing-with-checkbox-value)

Comment: That answer is a bad example of what to do as well, since `this.checked` is a directly accessible DOM property, `$(this).attr("checked")` is *tremendous* overkill.