# JQuery checkbox fail (why won't it changed "checked" attr?)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to toggle disabled/enabled for a form based on a users click of an edit checkbox.  Simple stuff.

While the disabling component works, the checkbox's default checked behavior is overriden.  I even tried to return attr("checked",true) to get it to work but no dice. I'm assuming that this might have to do with my markup (placing the checkbox in a div). Can't figure it out.

```
$(function(){
$('#target :input').attr('disabled','disabled');

$(':checkbox').toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).attr("checked",true);
        $('#target :input').attr('disabled',false);

    },
    function(){
        $('#target:input').attr('disabled','disabled');         
        $(this).attr("checked", false);


});
});
```

Thanks, 
Brendan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Devbook.co.uk noted, the [`toggle-event`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) method breaks the default behavior of the checkbox.

One solution is to use the `.change()` event, along with the `this.checked` property of the checkbox.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Efpr6/

```
$('#target :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('#toggler').change(function() {
    $('#target :input').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `$(this).attr('checked', 'checked')` to check it and `$(this).removeAttr('checked')` to uncheck it.

Comment: yeah so I tried that previously (and a bunch of other combinations). It didn't work. I just tried it again and still no dice.  Could this be a markup issue due to placing the checkbox in a div?

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(this).attr("checked",true);` to `$(this).attr("checked","checked");`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the attributes that you may think should have the value true or false, tend to have the attribute name used as the value, like this:

```
checked="checked"
disabled="disabled"
```

Some browsers will accept checked="true", but it's definitely not best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Think I found your solution though - have a look at this question

[Jquery toggle event is messing with checkbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355638/jquery-toggle-event-is-messing-with-checkbox-value)

Seems jQuery toggle doesn't play nice with checkboxes.

Comment: Interesting. Indeed the `.toggle()` event breaks it. It must do a `return false` or `event.preventDefault`. EDIT: Looks like it does: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/event.js#L987

Comment: yeah Devbook, I had that feeling as well.  I tried to get around it by returning $(this).attr("checked":"checked") but i guess that doesn't override the return false that toggle naturally implements.  Thanks for this confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).prop('checked', false);
$(this).prop('checked', true);
```

See this: 
 http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10248

this worked to my.