# Checkbox not unchecking visually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and within it is this:

```
<fieldset class="billing-address">
    <legend>Billing Address</legend>
  <ol>
        <li class="text combi"><label for="bill-address1">Address:</label> <input size="20" value="" name="basket_order:default:bill_address1" id="bill-address1"></li>
        <li class="text"><label for="bill-address2">Address:</label> <input size="20" value="" name="basket_order:default:bill_address2" id="bill-address2"></li>
        <li class="text"><label for="bill-address3">Town/City:</label> <input size="20" value="" name="basket_order:default:bill_address3" id="bill-address3"></li>
        <li class="text"><label for="bill-address4">Region:</label> <input size="20" value="" name="basket_order:default:bill_address4" id="bill-address4"></li>
        <li class="text"><label for="bill-post-code">Post code:</label> <input size="10" value="" name="basket_order:default:bill_postcode" id="bill-post-code"></li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
```

For reasons too biring to go into here, I cannot get at the HTML directly and need to do things via javascript. So, I add a checkbox and label above using the following:

```
$('.billing-address ol').before('<input type="checkbox" id="billing-add-different" /><label for="billing-add-different">My billing address is the same as my delivery address</label>');

    $('#billing-add-different').prop('checked',true).toggle(
        function(){
          $('.billing-address ol input, .billing-address ol select').css('background','#CCC').attr('disabled','disabled');
        },
        function(){
          $('.billing-address ol input, .billing-address ol select').css('background','#FFF').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
      );
```

This toggles the 'disabled' attribute and background colour depending on whether it's ticked or not.

However, though the function is firing, the checkbox is still visually checked.

I've made a jsfiddle to illustrate at http://jsfiddle.net/EFQuh/. The error occurs in Firefox 8.0, not sure about others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery toggle event is messing with checkbox value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355638/jquery-toggle-event-is-messing-with-checkbox-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the problem (probably the `toggle` function), but you can simplify your code to:

```
$('#billing-add-different').prop('checked',true).change(function(){
    $('.billing-address ol input, .billing-address ol select')
        .css('background-color', this.checked ? '#CCC' : '#FFF')
        .prop('disabled',this.checked);

}).change();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/EFQuh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event and check `this.checked` within the event's function.

Comment: Bugger. I wondered how the functionality was actually working. I'll remove that line from the answer, thanks.