# How to check and uncheck the select all check box using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

I have a toggle event for a select all checkbox that selects all my other checkboxes but the the select all check box won't check and uncheck how do I solve this the code is below:

```
$('#selectAllCheck').toggle(function () {
            $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
            }, function () {
                $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        });
```

Comment: You are passing two function to toggle, but there is no version of toggle() that supports that according to http://api.jquery.com/toggle/. I have to admit I don't fully understand what you want to do... Something with hiding and selecting/unselected boxes at the same time...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery toggle event is messing with checkbox value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355638/jquery-toggle-event-is-messing-with-checkbox-value)

Comment: @Yankee You're looking at the page for the display or hide elements toggle instead of the page for the toggle-event. I did the same thing. :D http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer: oops... Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/vjxHs/

```
$('#selectAllCheck').click(function () {  
    if ($(this).attr('checked')=='checked')
    {        
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selectAllCheck').click(function() {
   var status = $(this).attr('checked');
    if( ! status) {
        status = false;
    }
   $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',status);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

umm it should be something with your toggle event, I used hover and your code worked correctly

```
                $('#selectAllCheck').hover(
                    function () {
                        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
                    }, 
                    function () {
                        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
                    }
                );
```

almost the same code.. besides the hover

Answer (score 0):

Use This
**Javascript :**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function () {
        var $checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
        $('#selectAllCheck').toggle(function () {
            $checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
            return false;

        }, function () {
            $checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');
            return false;
        });
    });//]]>  

</script>
```