# JS overides check in the checkbox on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem regarding checkbox and JS. 
I wrote the following code but prop checked is not changing...

```
$( "#showCoupon" ).toggle(function() {

  $(".couponInputs").show(); 
  $("#cart-page #cart-coupon").height(135);
  document.getElementById("showCoupon").checked = true;

      }, function() {

   $(".couponInputs").hide(); 
  $("#cart-page #cart-coupon").height(50);
   document.getElementById("showCoupon").checked = false;

      });
```

Any idea why it is like this? show/hide and height change is working, just checking not...

```
    <div id="cart-coupon" class="item">
  <div id="couponField"> <strong>Apply coupon</strong>
    <input id="showCoupon" type="checkbox" style="
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px!important;
  bottom: -8px;
  position:  relative;
  float:  right;
  right: 10px;
  display:none;" class="mobile-show">
    <div class="couponInputs mobile-hide-cart">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" id="couponCode" name="CouponCode" size="16" placeholder="Enter coupon code:" />
      <input type="button" class="input-submit coupon-submit" value="Add Coupon" onclick="javascript: SC.Cart.applyCoupon();" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: Since you are using JQuery, why not use it for checked with `$("#showCoupon").prop("checked", true);`?

Comment: I have tried - its not working...

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: added in the main post

Comment: Your `.toggle()` function is running immediately and it first performs your "show" callback and then immediately performs your "hide" callback, which uncheckes the checkbox.

Comment: You can not add toggle event on checkbox , check the accepted answer at **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355638/jquery-toggle-event-is-messing-with-checkbox-value**